# jquery error for checkbox list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm getting the following syntax error for my list of check boxes:

```
unrecognized expression: input:checked[name=match_list[]]
```

HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="match_list[]" value="10">
   Item 10
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="match_list[]" value="20">
   Item 20
</label>
```

jQuery:

```
    var arr=[];

    $('input:checked[name=match_list[]]').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Any idea what the error is pointing to?  The syntax looks fine to me...

Comment: Why are you nesting your input elements inside your label elements?

Comment: I'm using twitter bootstrap

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I'm sure you can use either label's `for` or nest the input inside a label.. they both work and are valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$('input:checked[name="match_list[]"]').each(function(){
```

The quotes are only optional when it's easy to parse.

Regarding the input elements inside the label elements (a problem seen by Brian), you should use the for attribute :

```
<label class="checkbox" for=someid>Item 10</label>
<input type=someid "checkbox" name="match_list[]" value="10">
```